# How to disable options in a selection if this option is selected in another selection

Tags: html, jquery

I have three select group with same options.
How to disable options in a selection if this option is selected in another selection?

```
                        <select class="form-control" id="first_select" name="foo" required>
                            <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-control" id="second_select" name="foo2" required>
                            <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4>4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
<select class="form-control" id="third_select" name="foo3" required>
                                <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4>4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$(".form-control").on("change", function() {
   let selects = $(".form-control").not(this);
   let allSelects = $(".form-control");
   selects.each(function() {
      let options = $(this).find("option");
      options.each(function() {
         $(this).prop("disabled", false);
      });
   });

   allSelects.each(function() {
      let val = $(this).val();
      $(".form-control").not(this).find("option[value='" + val + "']").prop("disabled", true);

   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="first_select" name="foo" required>
  <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="second_select" name="foo2" required>
  <option disabled selected value="0">Wybierz zawód*</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="third_select" name="foo3" required>
    <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: my values ​​in the value field are two-fold and I throw an error value="foo foo"
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: optio

Comment: @ncti If you use the same code as in your question: There's an error as you have there  <option value="4> instead of  <option value="4">, maybe this is causing the error?

Comment: i'm using diffrent code, this is example value.
My value is two-fold like 'abc bca'

Comment: @ncti Can you make a Fiddle with your code? It's easier to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: @ncti I can't reproduce the error. I changed every dropdown without any errors though I can't say if it's working as expected. What steps are necessary to have this error occur?

Comment: When you choose two words value like "Technik Informatyk",
When I choose value with one word everything working fine

Comment: @ncti The Fiddle link doesn't work anymore, please create a new one.

Comment: @ncti The Fiddle doesn't work as the php doesn't get executed on jsfiddle. You could do another one with the generated HTML.

Comment: @ncti I fixed it in this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2d8fxLs7/. The issue was the line $(".wybor-zawodu").not(this).find("option[value=" + val + "]").prop("disabled", true); which I changed to $(".wybor-zawodu").not(this).find("option[value='" + val + "']").prop("disabled", true); (value= was missing backticks/single quatation marks).

Comment: Thank you for comment, but still when I choose in first select  some value I can also select the same value in  third select

Comment: @ncti It doesn't work for at least one value in the third select because the option values are different, for "Technik informatyk" the values in select 1 + 2 is "Technik informatyk", but for the 3rd select it's "Technikum Informatyczne".

Comment: in my php array is correct.
On mozilla it work fine, but in chrome when I selected something in first select all option in rest selects are disable

Comment: @ncti Can't reproduce the error in Chrome, it's working fine on my side.

Comment: something went wrong on my google chrome. The script works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Attention, your quotes for value 4 in second and third select is not closed correctly! This will fail the code.
For your option 1, to disable other selects options:

```js
function disableOthers(sender){
   var val = $(sender).val();

//To enable all if you change value.
 $('#second_select').children().attr('disabled', false);
    $('#third_select').children().attr('disabled', false);

  $('#second_select').children('option[value="' + val + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#third_select').children('option[value="' + val + '"]').attr('disabled', true);              
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" onchange="disableOthers(this)" id="first_select" name="foo" required>
  <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

  <select class="form-control" id="second_select" name="foo2" required>
                        <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
<select class="form-control" id="third_select" name="foo3" required>
                            <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: sorry, not wroking for third select

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-control').on('change', function(e){
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = this.value;
        $('.form-control').find("option").removeAttr('disabled', '');
        $('.form-control').find("option:contains('" + valueSelected + "')").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="first_select" name="foo" required>
        <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="second_select" name="foo2" required>
        <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="third_select" name="foo3" required>
        <option disabled selected value="0">Choose*</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Not working, I can choose 1,2,1, if 1 is choose it should be remove from third select

Comment: This is not what you asked in your question. You asked how to disable. You can change your question or post another question if you want. If I change my answer to how to remove, it will not be related to your question.

Comment: sorry not remove, disable.